# Does validating a site guarantee that it will look correct across all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I heard that as long as a page validates, it will always display correctly across browsers. I find that hard to believe because I know padding, for example, is dealt with differently by different browsers. So even if a page validates correctly, one browser might not show it correctly?

A basic example is padding. Doesn't IE6 deal with padding differently and therefore is the reason for specific stylesheets for Internet Explorer? And if so, is there any way to be 100% sure that a site will look the same across all browsers?

**UPDATE**

I'm fairly sure that it can't be gaurenteed 100%. But is there one example that I can use to prove this? AS I mentioned, I think padding is dealt with differently, but how?

Comment: In my experience validating a site doesn't do anything except make me feel a little bit better about myself

Comment: "is there any way to be 100% sure that a site will look the same across all browsers?" - Yes, test in each one of them.

Comment: Here's something to look at - http://validator.w3.org/docs/why.html

Comment: On topic, letting alone all old IE bugs and lack of HTML5 support, do you think IE6 would render CSS3 properties? Instead of swimming against the tide, look up Progressive Enhancement / Graceful Degradation.

Comment: `validating` is a `spell check` for html. It doesn't guarantee correct lookings =))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't mean that your website will look the same across all browsers, all it means is that you have adhered to the standards. And that **if** - and only **if** - all browsers implement all the standards exactly according to the standards, that your site will then look exactly the same across all browsers. The reality is that not all browsers have always adhered perfectly to all the standards. Therefore, it does not mean that your site will look the same in all browsers.

Newer version of browsers have adhered more and more to the standards, so they're on the right track, but especially older versions of browsers, and to be even more specific, Microsoft's older versions of browsers, have not really adhered to the standards.

Comment: Well, OP uses `padding` as an example, and padding has nothing to do with HTML. Padding is merely styling, part of CSS, while HTML is structure.

Comment: This is still wrong. Validation has nothing to do with how markup is displayed in the browser.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - How do you know if OP is talking about [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) or [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) validation?

Comment: Right, taking both validators in consideration your answer makes sense. Though, there's still the evolution factor - just because your HTML is valid HTML5 does not mean that older browsers which do not support HTML5 as IE7 and below would display it correctly. And that is letting alone JS, which can also alter styles and is the most affected part by Microsoft's proprietary stuff. Lastly, experimental features such as vendor-prefixed CSS properties (e.g. `-webkit-*`) may also make the rendered output different across browsers.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Fair point, I could have been more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Validation and cross browser compatibility are 2 completely separate things. 
Today, since there is no more IE6 and mostly no IE7 most browsers already behave similar.

IE6 and 7 can decide to collapse padding with margin in a couple of scenarios.

There are over 20 combinations of hasLayout margin padding and child parent which cause IE7 to collapse paddings, which it never should.

There are tricks, but validating HTML is certainly not one of them.

What you probably mean is the Quirksmode.

IE in quirksmode has the oldschool box model, which calculates real width = defined width, inkl padding and border. Standart behaviour would be real width = defined width + padding + border.

So if you use the correct doctype, IE 6 and 7 will add paddings to the width, if you dont use doctype, IE6 and 7 will behave like IE5 with the old school box model.

However, you only need to declare the doctype, it doesnt need to validate.

**Proof that validation doesn't help:**

```
<div style="float:left; margin-right:5px;">Double margin bug example in IE 6</div>
<div style="float:left;">Double margin bug example in IE 6</div>
```

This code is perfectly legal and will validate, however it will trigger IE6's infamous double margin bug and look differently across browsers.

There are thousands of other examples, just like this one (i am actually not joking)

Answer (score 0):

No. [Validation is a formal thing](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/validation.html) and does not guarantee even conformance to a specification, still less “looking the same”, which isn’t even something that the specifications require or recommend.

(“HTML5 validation” is partly different, namely running undocumented checks against some unknown versions of a mutable draft or “living standard”. But surely it does not guarantee anything like “looking the same”.)